# Find if a value exists in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists like this:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I now want to find if a value exists in `my_list`, and I need to do this in the most efficient way. I will use it in the following way:

```
if my_value in my_list:
    # do something
```

I have tried 2 versions as below.

```
# 1
if any(my_value in sublist for sublist in my_list)

# 2
for sublist in my_list:
    if my_value in sublist:
        return True
```

I find version 1 easier to read and doesn't require a separate function call. But does the any() function stop when it finds the value, or does it loop through the entire list? And is there a better, or more pythonic, way of doing this lookup?

Comment: Does your objective is only to find a specific value exists or not in the entire  list of list?

Comment: yes, [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) stops as soon as it has found the element.

Comment: if you are only interested if an element exists and you do not care where (assuming you will do this several times), why don't you create a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and check against that? the look-up would be one-dimensional and constant-time (but the initialization of the `set` will need to iterate over all elements).

Comment: `any` pretty much works the way the logical OR operator works. They both exhibit short-circuit behavior as soon as they find the first truth value.

Comment: If you’re not already using it, the built-in `timeit` library is an excellent tool for determining the (time) efficiency of a code statement.

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: val in x, my_list))` will provide all sublist where your value is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference seems to be negligible with the second version only slightly faster.

```
my_list = [np.random.randint(1, 10000, 1000) for v in range(1000)]
my_value = np.random.randint(1, 10000, 1)[0]
def v1(my_list):
    if any(my_value in sublist for sublist in my_list):
        return True
    return False

def v2(my_list):
    for sublist in my_list:
        if my_value in sublist:
            return True
    return False

print(my_value)
%timeit v1(my_list)
%timeit v2(my_list)

>> 3012
>> 56.9 µs ± 3.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>> 51.2 µs ± 383 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was going to go for 1 for simplicity since speed difference is negligible. I was also wondering if there was any other way of doing this, I assume there is not any better way.